# Laravel: how to get data with post

Tags: php, laravel

I've created a function in my routes that take some data from a view and send to another view

```
Route::post('/trans',  function(){
    $j = Input::get('r');
    return view('movs.create')->with($j);
});
```

this route take the data from this form

```
<form action="/trans" method="POST">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="r" value={{$cooperado->id}}>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                          <span>+</span>
                        </button>
                      </span>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

but cant set the data in this other form on `'movs.create'`

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('movs.store') }}">
          <div class="form-group">
              @csrf
              <label for="name">ID COOP:</label>
              <input type="number" class="form-control" name="id_coop" readonly/> <-- data must be setted here
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="price">VALOR MOVIMENTACAO:</label>
              <input type="number" step=0.01 class="form-control" name="valor"/>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
      </form>
```

when i try to set the data in id_coop input, laravel says that the variable doesnt exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[with](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views#passing-data-to-views) works with key value pair

```
Route::post('/trans',  function(){
    $j = Input::get('r');
    return view('movs.create')->with('j',$j);
   // or return view('movs.create', compact('j')); // it will extract in 
    //blade as $j
    // or return view('movs.create', ['j' => $j]); 
});
```

// you can fetch that data in blade as `{{$j}}`

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" name="id_coop" value="{{$j ?? ''}}" readonly/>
```

Example of `with`,

```
return view('greeting')->with('name', 'Victoria'); // name as key and Victorial as value.
```

`{{$j ?? ''}}` if data is not set then '' value.

Answer (score 3):

To set data in the create form, you may need to add a `value` attribute to the `id_coop` input:

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" name="id_coop" value="{{ $j }} readonly/>
```

Also, `->with()` needs to be a key (variable name) and value:

```
Route::post('/trans',  function(){
    $j = Input::get('r');
    return view('movs.create')->with('id_coop', $j);
});
```

This would mean you use `{{ $id_coop }}` instead.

Answer (score 1):

//controller

```
public function Postdata(Request $request){

        $data['j'] = Input::get('r');
        return view('movs.create',$data);


    }
```

//route

```
Route::post('/trans','yourController@Postdata');
```

//your view

```
<form method="post" action="{{ url('/store') }}">
          <div class="form-group">
              @csrf
              <label for="name">ID COOP:</label>
              <input type="number" class="form-control" name="id_coop" value="{{ $j }}" readonly/> <-- data must be setted here
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="price">VALOR MOVIMENTACAO:</label>
              <input type="number" step=0.01 class="form-control" name="valor"/>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
      </form>
```

//store route

```
Route::post('/store','yourController@Savedata');
```

hope this helps